# Does Python assume a symbol is a type before trying to see if it is a function?

Tags: python

In Python the symbol `int` is used both as a type and a built-in function.  But when I use `int` in the REPL, or ask for its type, the REPL tells me it is a type.

```
>>> int
<type 'int'>
>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
```

This is fine, but `int` is also a built-in function: it is listed in the table of built-in functions [right in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Other built-in functions are reported like this in the REPL:

```
>>> abs
<built-in function abs>
>>> type(abs)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

But I can't get `type` to show me this for `int`. Now clearly I *can* use `int` as a function if I want to (sorry for using `map` instead of a comprehension, I'm just trying to make a point):

```
>>> map(int, ["4", "2"])
[4, 2]
```

So Python knows to use the function.  But why does `type` pick the type over the function?  Nothing in [the definition of the `type` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) says to expect this.  And then as a follow-up, what is the meaning of this expression:

```
id(int)
```

Is this giving me the `id` of the type or the function.  I expect the former.  Now if it is the former, how would I get the id of the built-in function `int`?

Comment: All types are callable. For example when doing `class Foo: pass`, you create a new type `Foo` but you can also call it `Foo()` to create a new object of that type.

Comment: `REPL` means `read–eval–print loop`?

Comment: @poke Yes, thanks, types (and functions, classes, objects with `__call__` and many other things are callable); the placement of `int` in the documentation in the list of built-in functions led me to believe there was some other special object here.  I am beginning to think this is one misleading piece of documentation, and if I were to rewrite the docs, I would remove them.

Comment: Well it *is* a special object since it’s one of the few types that is natively implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one thing called `int` and only one thing called `abs`.

The difference is that `int` is a class, and `abs` is a function. Both, however, are callable. When you call `int(42)`, that calls the `int` class's constructor, returning an instance of class `int`.

It's not really much different to:

```
class Int(object):

  def __init__(self, init_val=0):
    self.val = init_val

obj = Int(42)
print Int, type(Int), obj, type(obj)
```

Here, `Int` is callable, and can be used to construct instances of the class.

Once you realise this, the rest will follow.

Comment: Nice, that does makes perfect sense! But then one would wonder why the docs have thrown in `int` and `str` and `float` and friends into the section on Built-in Functions, and then described them as if they were functions.  I suspect it might be because they are deferring the more technical details of types until later in the docs; I don't know.  But they sure made it look like there was some overloading going on.  Glad to see there is just one meaning for `int`. :)

Comment: @RayToal: I am not sure of the exact reasons the docs are organised the way they are, but that could be historic.

Comment: @RayToal It’s because the type creation for those types also includes a fair amount of parsing and type conversion. So it makes sense to list them as built-in functions since they can be used to convert things into common other types.

Comment: I've just followed a few more links in the docs and ended up [in this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric).  I see the sentence "The constructors int(), float(), and complex() can be used to produce numbers of a specific type." so they do give a nod to the fact that constructors are in play here.  I kind of wish they didn't list those things _as functions_ in Section 2; for a second I thought Python had - gasp - overloading.  Though perhaps it does, as constructors have the same name as their types....

Comment: There's some subtlety with `type` itself. Historically, `type` was a function, which took one argument and returned its type (e.g. `type(3) -> int`. Later, `type` became a class, but the old usage was not removed for backwards compatibility. Thus, now, `type` functions as both a plain function `type(obj)` and as a constructor `type(name, bases, dict)`.

Comment: @RayToal: Technically, `int` can return `long` instances (under Python 2.x), which makes it like a constructor but not exactly. (You can get the same effect with a user class by overloading `__new__` rather than `__init__`).

Comment: Now _that's_ really interesting.  I guess the best explanation is that Python lets lots of things be callable, and constructors, i.e., types being called because they are callable, don't _have_ to return objects of that type.  I still wish the docs didn't _explicitly say_ that these things were built-in functions, even though they look like functions.  Yes there might be a pedagogical value in mis-labeling things but ultimately I think there is more harm done here than necessary.  Just MHO.

Comment: Also @nneonneo, I did notice that `type(type)` produced `<type 'type'>` but wanted to keep the question short.  But your explanation helps with this too.

Comment: @RayToal: I think you have a point about labelling these as functions. Might be worth considering filing a documentation bug? https://docs.python.org/2/bugs.html